# sorting available products by date in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I haw two tables one is product and one is date. Date table represent a calendar in format date when products are not available. every date(day) is in its one row and it has own id and product id. 
I haw to show product that are available in some range of date say 2012-05-05 - 2012-05-20 .
Can someone give me example how can i do that? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from product p join date d 
on p.product_id = d.product_id
where d.date between '2012-05-05' and '2012-05-20' order by d.date desc
```

Comment: I haw to select products that are not in that range ! date table represent dates when product isn't available! dose it need to be not betweaen ?

Comment: then try this `select * from 'test_table'
where end_date < CAST('2009-12-15' AS DATE)
or start_date > CAST('2010-01-02' AS DATE)`

Comment: table date haw every single date(day) entry in new row i don't haw start end date !

Answer (score 0):

Join both tables and filter the records according to the condition

```
select * from product p join date d 
on p.product_id = d.product_id
where d.date between '2012-05-05' and '2012-05-20'
```

Comment: I haw to select products that are not in that range ! date table represent dates when product isn't available!